# Getting Values of the two rows before the selected row POSTRESQL

Tags: postgresql, select, update

I want to update an row according to the values of two rows before the row how can i do that?

Let's assume my table looks like this

```
ID         amount

1           1
2           3
7           5
```

And i want to do this

```
UPDATE amount 
FROM table 
SET amount = (AmounToFRowOneBefore + AmounToFRowTwoBefore)/2  
WHERE ID=7;
```

Expected output would be

```
 ID         amount

    1           1
    2           3
    7           2
```

And if I do this I don't know anything about the two rows before so no ID or anything is there a query to select the values before the selected row?

Comment: Adding the expected output would be helpful. Also tag your RDBMS, like SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle, ....

Comment: Depending on your dbms and version you can use the LAG() function to refer to these values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: And how can i use lag to get the value of the n row before the selected one ?

Comment: `I don't know anything about the two rows before` I suppose there is an ORDER in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either a window function:

```
with ct as
(
  select
      id,
      amount,
      (sum(amount) over (order by id rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding)) / 2 as new_amount
  from
      t
)
update t
set    amount = ct.new_amount
from
    ct
where
    t.id = ct.id
    and ct.id = 3;
```

Or use a subquery that returns the 2 previous rows:

```
update t
set amount = (select sum(t3.amount) / 2
             from (select amount 
                   from t t2
                   where t2.id < t.id 
                   order by id desc 
                   limit 2) t3)
where
    t.id = 3;
```

Check them for performance.

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id |             amount
> -: | -----------------:
>  1 |                  1
>  2 |                  3
>  3 | 2.0000000000000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=62c371349a669460e95f658849181569)*